# Finding find a^s mod b

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo, pow

We are given 3 numbers: a,s and b, each varying in the range between 1 and 1000000. We need to find pow(a,s)%b. Obviously, we can not use the simple pow function because we could not generate big number such as 1000000<sup>1000000</sup>. This is the solution of the problem:

```
sol=1
for(int i=0;i<s;i++) 
{
            sol = sol * a;
            sol = sol % b;
}

print sol
```

I don't understand this algorithm. Can someone explain it to me?

P.S. Where can I find more algorithms for solving non-trivialc math problems such as this one?
Cheers!

Comment: For the record, this is a very slow algorithm: it runs in O(s) time. It's not much harder to write an algorithm that runs in O(log s) time, making it suitable for much, much larger values of s (e.g., for use in real-world RSA encryption).

Comment: Hmm. Yes, it's quite suboptimal. Instead of repeated multiplication one should really try repeated squaring.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the algorithm you wrote is not at all optimized, since it's linear in s, while you can easily write a log(s) one, as you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).

That said, there isn't much to explain: you just have to know that

```
a*b mod N = ((a mod N) * ( b mod N)) mod N
```

and that

```
a^s = a*a*...*a s times
```

and it immediately follows that your algorithm computes the result in the naive way.

Comment: Since  s is 1000000, O(s) is good. But i still don't understand what you wrote. b mod b?

Comment: @Want It's a typo, sorry

Answer (score 4):

a<sup>s</sup> mod b = (a • a<sup>s-1</sup>) mod b = (a mod b) • (a<sup>s-1</sup> mod b) mod b = ...

As you can see the first step is trivial, while the second step is a known property of modulo. So you can iterate and find a<sup>s</sup> mod b.

As other mentioned you can do better. For the other method you can go to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). But I will explain the idea behind this algorithm: Represent the number `s` in binary so you can write `s` in the following way:

s=∑(2<sup>i</sup> • b<sub>i</sub>) where each b<sub>i</sub> is 0 or 1.

So: a<sup>s</sup> mod b = a<sup>∑(2<sup>i</sup> • b<sub>i</sub>)</sup> mod b, so you can just do the multiplication when the LSB = 1 then shift right the exponent ...